# How to change "href" attribute of link has specific "href" using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, href

If a pages has several links as such:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/linka.html">Link A</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/linkb.html">Link B</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/linkc.html">Link C</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/linkd.html">Link D</a>
```

How do I change them all on page load to :

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/folder/linka.html">Link A</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/folder/linkb.html">Link B</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/folder/linkc.html">Link C</a>
<a href="http://www.domain.com/folder/linkd.html">Link D</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to select all anchor tag that `href` attribute of them start with "link" using  [`[name^=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector and end with ".html" using [`[name$=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector. Then use [`.attr(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to iterate selected element and change href attribute of them in function.

```
$("a[href^='link'][href$='.html']").attr("href", function(i, attr){
    return "folder/" + attr;
});
```

```js
$("a[href^='link'][href$='.html']").attr("href", function(i, attr){
  return "folder/" + attr;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="linka.html">Link A</a>
<a href="linkb.html">Link B</a>
<a href="linkc.html">Link C</a>
<a href="linkd.html">Link D</a>
```

Also you can write the code in `$(document).ready(function(){//code})` to running after page load.

Comment: You can check if the file is a `.html`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.each($("a[href^='link'][href$='.html']"),function(){
$(this).attr("href",document.URL+"folder/"+$(this).attr("href"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="linka.html">Link A</a>
<a href="linkb.html">Link B</a>
<a href="linkc.html">Link C</a>
<a href="linkd.html">Link D</a>
```

Comment: This adds the url at the beginning of the of the http:// giving an invalid link. I've updated original post.